# Calling C Pointers in vb.net

Tags: c, vb.net, pointers, dll

im new here, forgive me if im not using the right terms. I have a c compiled dll which I am calling from vb 2013. Problems im having is in calling the pointers in the c dll. I did my best and managed to read from int *, but how about u_int * or float *? Below are the codes I have written so far.

my.dll :

```
BCAPDLL_API int * __stdcall myfunc1(int * localPtr){
localPtr[0] = 100;
localPtr[1] = 200;
localPtr[2] = 300;
localPtr[3] = 400;
return localPtr;
}

BCAPDLL_API u_int * __stdcall myfunc2(u_int * localPtr){
localPtr[0] = 100;
localPtr[1] = 200;
localPtr[2] = 300;
localPtr[3] = 400;
return localPtr;
}

BCAPDLL_API float * __stdcall myfunc3(float * localPtr){
localPtr[0] = 100;
localPtr[1] = 200;
localPtr[2] = 300;
localPtr[3] = 400;
return localPtr;
}
```

in vb.net :

```
    Sub Main()

    Dim mycomm(4) As Integer
    Dim localPtr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4)
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = testFunc(localPtr)
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, mycomm, 0, 4)

    For i As Integer = 0 To 3
        MsgBox(Marshal.ReadInt32(mycomm, i * Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Int32))))
    Next i
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(localPtr)

    End Sub
```

This function gets me all the values from the dll for the function with int *, however for u_int * and float *, I cant use the same approach as Marshal class doesn't support UIntPtr; and FloatPtr doesn't exist in vb.net. How do I go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it too late to switch to C# (which does support pointers)?

Comment: Does that mean its not possible in vb.net? Do I have to learn C# simply because u_int * and float *?

Comment: Excuse me if I am wrong, but aren't you just getting a pointer to a value in memory? You should be able to keep your `IntPtr` and then `Marshal.Copy` the data into a `byte[]` and use `BitConverter.ToSingle(myCopiedBytes, 0)` to get the actual value of `float`.

Comment: Can you provide some codes example?

Comment: Thanks TyCobb!!! Finally got it to work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim oSize As Integer = 4
    Dim mycomm(oSize) As Byte
    Dim localPtr As IntPtr
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = testFunc3(localPtr)

    For i = 0 To oSize - 1
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, mycomm, 0, oSize)
        MsgBox(BitConverter.ToSingle(mycomm, 0))
        ptr = IntPtr.Add(ptr, Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Single)))
    Next i
```